# Determine the location of the snippet to be removed

Tags: javascript, security, files

I am absolutely unfamiliar with Drupal, but have a task of removing a snippet of code from one of its pages.

The snippet in question had been determined by Google Wabmaster tools to be malware, and I need to just delete it from the code.

How can I find that directory via FTP (or cPanel?)

Or perhaps there's some other, better – easier – way to remove the malicious snippet?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/module-to-list-menu-router-path-debug-info I will suggest this question is a duplicate of mine, but let us know here in the comments if it is not, and if so why. For what it's worth, you probably can't find the "directory" via FTP because Drupal isn't built to expose the underlaying file system. (In theory the directory could still exist, but if so, this question is unrelated to Drupal)

Comment: The opera browser doesn't report any malware on the page, so it's not clear to me whether you have already solved the problem. Without additional information, it is impossible to say whether the malware is included in the content (in the database) or in code.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Letharion! This is very likely just the answer I was looking for! Wanna try to apply it now. Problem is, I'm completely unfamiliar with Drupal to a degree that I wouldn't even know where to insert that snippet of code mentioned in the answer to your question. Could you help, please?

Comment: See this question for how to create a module: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/how-to-create-a-empty-module In the linked to post, Clive the mentions hook_init and dpm. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99556/how-to-implement-a-hook/ for that.