# How to implement a hook?

Tags: hooks

I've been told I should implement this hook thing, what does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

The details for how to implement a hook varies from one hook to another.

One of the easiest examples though, is [hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init). Hook init is a generic way of saying "Do something on every un-cached page load". The _un_cached part is important, if you are logged out when testing this, probably nothing will happen.

In a [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/how-to-create-a-empty-module) file named "my_module.module", one would implement hook_init like this

```
<?php
my_module_init() {
}
```

To make something actually happen, we can add a call to [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7).

```
<?php
my_module_init() {
  drupal_set_message('Hello Drupal!');
}
```

If you have [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) installed, a common way to do debugging could look something like this:

```
<?php
my_module_init() {
  dpm(menu_get_item());
}
```

For more details and examples, see [What is the basic concept behind hooks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-the-basic-concept-behind-hooks)

Comment: Most common used hooks here seems to be ones from `alter` family, especially `form_alter`. Would be worth explaining it a bit. And put more stress on the `my_module` part of function names, please. I still see people confused by it, and leaving it be - then surprised it fails for them.